# How to hide original mount points with bind mount?

Tags: filesystems, fstab, bind-mount

I use OpenMediaVault, a NAS software on top of Debian Wheezy. This system usually mounts the file systems at /media/, but that is cumbersome to type and to identify.

As such, I've modified my `fstab` file to bind mount two file systems to different locations. Check the last two lines of my `fstab` file:

```
UUID=e2063e64-379f-4d8f-a8c4-75c1439636d6 /             ext4    errors=remount-ro    0 1
UUID=e5187843-c48d-411c-8716-fc35901d7901 none          swap    sw                   0 0

# >>> [openmediavault]
UUID=4d98f9b3-512f-4d8b-96c6-4c6c4caaab40 /media/4d98f9b3-512f-4d8b-96c6-4c6c4caaab40 xfs defaults,nofail,noexec,usrquota,grpquota 0 2
UUID=52efb2d8-3120-4113-88b0-01531f784ae7 /media/52efb2d8-3120-4113-88b0-01531f784ae7 ext4 defaults,nofail,user_xattr,noexec,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0,acl 0 2
# <<< [openmediavault]

# Remount /home with executable permissions
UUID=52efb2d8-3120-4113-88b0-01531f784ae7 /media/52efb2d8-3120-4113-88b0-01531f784ae7 none remount,exec 0 0

# Bind mount already-mounted filesystems to additional locations
/media/4d98f9b3-512f-4d8b-96c6-4c6c4caaab40 /storage none bind 0 0
/media/52efb2d8-3120-4113-88b0-01531f784ae7 /home none bind 0 0
```

This works nicely but has one small "issue". Applications which lists all the mounted partitions will have duplicate mount points for those two mounts, one from the `/media/<uuid>` and the other from the bind mount.

Of course, they both point to the same exact location and both work. But I'd like these applications to just list one of those mount points and the more recognizable ones. In my real example, that is `/home` and `/storage`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: dont use those applications

Comment: it is possible, though. you would have to separate the mount *namespaces*. doing so might be a bit more annoying to setup than youd like, though.

Comment: Have you considered using symbolic links instead of bind mount?

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat possible, depending on the apps you use and if they rely on udisks2.

Adding `x-gvfs-hide` to the mount options in `fstab` would hide certain mount points from such apps.

Example:

```
# forcibly hide device in user interface
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-HITACHI_HTS723232A7A364_E3834563KRG2HN-part1   /home/davidz/Data  auto  defaults,x-gvfs-hide 0 0
```

https://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/tree/monitor/udisks2/what-is-shown.txt

Comment: Anonymous downvoter, care to explain what's wrong here?

Comment: I had to actually add `comment=x-gvfs-hode`, but it didn't work anyways. The apps in question didn't hide them that is.

Comment: Why `comment=`? Where does this come from? Also be aware it's `x-gvfs-hide` not `x-gvfs-hode`

Comment: I know it's `hide`, it was a typo. Well, I added just what you said and my partitions were unmountable. I searched a bit and I saw everyone eles recommend the `comment=` thing, so I added that.

Comment: The `comment=` thing is not listed in the official docs, though. Anyway, if `x-gvfs-hide` doesn't work, you apps do not rely on udisks2.

Comment: The apps might not work with that, but I wasn't yet able to test that because the partitions don't even mount with that parameter...